Safe-cli issue with Trezor
I am trying to send any transaction using the safe-cli with a Trezor wallet.
The Trezor address gets imported correctly through load_trezor_cli_owners, but I receive the following error when trying to send a transaction.
HwDevice exception: Unexpected message

Any idea how to solve the problem? I've tried different transactions types with no luck.
I am on Mac Sonoma 14.5.
Thank you.

Thanks for your question. It seems like the problem is coming from Safe-CLI. Could you please open an issue by clicking here, and provide as much detail as possible? Such as the stack trace, configuration, and explain as specifically as possible what you were trying to do.
Thank you in advance  Best, Louis
